# Will DROP DATABASE stop the killing process?

Tags: mysql

I've got a problem with a KILL command that has been running for over an hour now. The problem arose when I killed an INSERT of millions of records that took forever. The kill now uses most of the memory available on the database server and it slows down developing mightily at the moment.

I read in [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5654/internal-reason-for-killing-process-taking-up-long-time-in-mysql/5664#5664) that there's no way to kill a killing process, but dropping the entire database was never mentioned. I can't find information in the manuals or on Google.

We don't need this database, we have more development databases to work on. So the question is:

**Will dropping the database cancel the kill process?**

-- *Why don't you just try it?*

Well, if the server gets even more clogged up than it is now, me and my team mates might as well go home. I have no way of testing this solution.

Comment: I think you cant drop the database until a transaction with an insert or something else exists, 'cause of the database locks.

Comment: In that case we just gotta hope it'll be done after lunch break. ;)

Comment: restart the mysql service?

Comment: No, it'll pick up where it'd left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The database is locked during the rollback. Dropping the database is not possible at this stage.